# lightning-datatable - cellAttributes

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am using a lightning-datatable.  I have a description field for one of my columns that I would like to better display the text.  I would like to either be able to have 3 lines for this field if the data needs it.  I tried to use wrapText: true but that just bleeds the text into the next field.  I tried looking for a full list of column cellAttributes without success.  How can I display the Description field so it shows multiple lines if needed?

```
    const cols = [
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status__c', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 90},
    { label: 'Number', fieldName: 'Group_Number__c', type: 'text', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 125 },
    { label: 'Eff Date', fieldName: 'Effective_Date__c', type: 'date-local', sortable: "true", initialWidth: 10},
    { label: 'Description', fieldName: 'Description__c', type: 'longtext', sortable: "true",  initialWidth: 520, editable: true, wrapText: false},
    {label: 'Actions', type: 'action', fixedWidth: 70, fixedHeight: 90,
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
           // menuAlignment: 'right'
        }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [number of visible lines](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification) as `data-table` attribute `wrap-text-max-lines`. Like this.

```
<lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                wrap-text-max-lines=3>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked along with ensuring the column had wraptTest: True.